# How to stop reattempt of making connection with RabbitMq, Postgress in case of failure in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am working on spring boot and wants to make limited reattempt of making connection with RabbitMQ, because `@RabbitListener` is attempt again and again till RabbitMQ up.
The scenario is that whenever spring boot tries to make connection then in case of failure spring boot retries again and again which makes log file lengthy and consumes more space.
Therefore I want make reattempt **max 3 times** and after 3 attempts, if RabbitMQ not up then stop RabbitListener until connection up.

What will be general way to attempt it for all type of connections like these?

Comment: `which makes log file lengthy and consumes more space.` sounds like you need a tool like `logrotate`...? But more importantly, why is your connection to RabbitMQ/DB failing so often...?

Comment: My connection is not failing currently, but in case if connection losses then spring boot retry to connect. It goes continuously and not stopping therefore I want it to retry max 3 times. If in 3 three attempts, connection is not made then there is not need to retry again.